# Add unique id to nested array in user model Mongoosedb

Tags: node.js, express, model, mongoose

Im trying to add a unique track id to a nested array in user favourites array inside the user model. New to this, so a little help would be great

User.js  (model)

```
var UserSchema   = new Schema({
 name: String,
 username: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }},
 password: { type: String, required: true, select: false },
 favorites: [Track],
 meta : [{
    favorites_count : {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    friends_count: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
 }]

});

apiRouter.route('/users/:user_id/favorites/:track_id')
        .post(function(req, res){
            User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.user_id, {
                $addToSet: {"favorites": {track_id: req.body.track_id}},
                $inc: { "meta.favorites_count": 1 }
                // $set: { "meta.favorites_count": 1}
            }, 
            {safe: true, upsert: true}, function(err, user) {

                    if (err) res.send(err);

                    res.json({ message: "Track Favorited" });

                }
            );
        })
```

Comment: Is there a specific question you'd like to ask, or are you just sharing your intentions?

Comment: I cant get it to work, so any idea on the best practice would be great.....

Answer (score 0):

You should define your `favorites` in your schema like the following:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  username: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }},
  password: { type: String, required: true, select: false },
  favorites: [{ type : ObjectId, ref: 'Track' }],
  meta : [{
     favorites_count : {
     type: Number,
     default: 0
   },
   friends_count: {
     type: Number,
     default: 0
   }
 }]
});
```

And change your route to:

```
apiRouter.route('/users/:user_id/favorites/:track_id')
    .post(function(req, res){
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.user_id, {
            $addToSet: {"favorites": req.body.track_id},
            $inc: { "meta.favorites_count": 1 }
            // $set: { "meta.favorites_count": 1}
        }, 
        {safe: true, upsert: true}, function(err, user) {
                if (err) res.send(err);
                res.json({ message: "Track Favorited" });
            }
        );
    });
```

**EDIT:** Answer the question from your comments.
If the track id is already present in your `favorites` array then you should change the your query to like this:

```
var track_id = req.body.track_id;

User.findOneAndUpdate({
     _id: req.params.user_id,
     favorites: {$nin: [track_id]}
  },{
     $addToSet: {"favorites": track_id },
     $inc: { "meta.favorites_count": 1 }
     // $set: { "meta.favorites_count": 1}
  },{
     safe: true,
     upsert: true
  },function(err, user) {
     if (err) res.send(err);
     res.json({ message: "Track Favorited" });
  }
);
```

So you should exclude your documents that already contains `track_id` in `favorites` array

Comment: Thanks for that, works great.. The only issue I have is detecting when the record is not modified, for example the track id is already present. I dont want to increment favorites_count unless a unique record is added..